# Store char into a char matrix (C programming)

Tags: c, matrix, char

I'm trying to develop a robot simulator. He can move inside a virtual world (100x100 char matrix). I can give him orders like "move right 50 positions", "move left 80 positions", etc.

I've got all this stuff done. The problem is that I want to show the final position of the robot in the screen by storing an "x" char in its final position.

For example, assume that its final position is (50,50), I should store a x char in the world[50][50].

I've tried by doing:

```
world[50][50]="x";
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

A char is represented by `'x'` in C. `"x"` is a string. You should use single quotes on the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes:

```
world[50][50] = 'x'.
```

Answer (score 1):

double quotes "x" - is a string, mean that "x" = 'x' + '\0'.

single quotes 'x' - is a single char 'x' = 120 .

Answer (score 0):

Since its a char matrix so use single quotes(' ') instead of double quotes.

world[50][50]='x';

this will solve your problem.